# Using ctypes in Python to load XLL libraries?

Tags: python, ctypes, xll

We have "in house" XLL libraries that we make for Excel.  Assuming we match the 32-bit/64-bit ness between the XLL and python, can we use ctypes to load and use the XLL (treating it as a DLL)?

Has anybody done this?  Any known issues and work arounds?

**Edit:** I tried doing this and no luck so far.  The Excel add-on works on 32-bit excel, so I figured it was a 32 bit library.

```
lib = ctypes.CDLL(xll)
```

In 64 bit python, I get

```
c:\anaconda3\envs\py38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371
    372         if handle is None:
--> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374         else:
    375             self._handle = handle
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

In 32 bit python, I get:

```
c:\Anaconda\envs\py39_32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    380
    381         if handle is None:
--> 382             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    383         else:
    384             self._handle = handle

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\public\ExcelAddons\alib.0.86\alib.xll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: I just tried this on my [xlOil](https://pypi.org/project/xlOil/) XLL (64-bit) and it works fine, so wonderings if there are missing dependencies?  You check with [this](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies).  Side question: does your XLL export any accessible functions (i.e. not wrapped in XLOPER)?

Comment: The xll might need to load `xlcall32.dll`. This can be found in the Excel binary directory. Despite its name this dll might be 32- or 64-bit depending on the bitness of your Excel installation. It provides the implementation of the `Excel4()` function (and others) which the xll would use to call into Excel (eg to register functions when loaded). As @stevecu asks: are the functions currently used as spreadsheet functions? If so they will likely pass the XLOPER structure to & fro.